# Skype won't start on xfce with Slackware 64 bit multilib

Tags: xfce, slackware, skype

I'm trying to install Skype under Slackware 14.0 x64 multilib with xfce 4.10 but I get issue that I can't resolve.

I have installed various versions of Skype (static, dynamic, newer, older, etc.) but they all have one thing in common - they won't appear when I'm on xfce. If I will start KDE everything works fine.

There is no error, any trace in logs, `ps aux|grep skype` shows running process named `skype` but nothing appears and I can't make Skype window appear.

I don't know what to include as it seems to me that Skype is working (on KDE) but there is some issue with xfce, but I've no idea where to start resolving this. Any ideas?

Edit:

If I will try running Skype as root I receive such output:

```
bash-4.2# skype
bash-4.2# No protocol specified
*** glibc detected *** /usr/share/skype/skype: double free or corruption      (!prev): 0xf9370e48 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/share/skype/lib32/libc.so.6(+0x78027)[0xf2d91027]
/usr/share/skype/lib32/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xf2f2e9bf]
/usr/share/skype/lib32/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdaPv+0x1b)[0xf2f2ea0b]
[0xf673f2f7]
======= Memory map: ========
(...)
```

After quick googling I've found a lot of various possible causes of that behavior (most of which vere related to some old versions - 2.x and such), but neither running

```
QT_IM_MODULE="" skype
```

nor

```
MALLOC_CHECK_=1 skype
```

helped.

Creating `Logs` directory in Skype's directory also didn't help.

Edit: Half year later and I still can't get it working, I've updated Skype to 4.2.0.13 and Slackware to 14.1, and now it throws no error, but of course doesn't work too, running `LD_DEBUG=all skype` stops at:

```
     13254: symbol=dup2;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
     13254: binding file /usr/libexec/gconfd-2 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `dup2' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

But I don't know how to resolve that since this throws no error, so I have to use osme else windows manager now. Unfortunately all other managers on my system are able to run skype, only xfce is failing here.

Comment: Do you have a "system tray" running in your panel (I assume you have `tint2`)? It's not that it just appears minimized to the systray and that's why you don;t see it by any chance?

Comment: I don't have access to that machine now (I'm at work) so I can't check it now, but if it w'd appear in systray I'w be able to pull it from there, but that's a good trace as it looks Skype is running but i simply can't see it. If it'll be something like that I'll feel like really stupid man ;)

Comment: Let's hope it is, at least that is easy to fix (though your pride might be harder :-). It might also be that you have multiple systrays running (if you use another panel application) and that might cause conflicts. I have both tint2 and the Cinnamon panel on my desktop and they sometimes get confused as to who should have the systray.

Comment: I haven't installed any other systray or similar application, but I don't know how it looks in vanilla Slackware. I switched from Windows to Slackware in January so such silly mistake would be ashaming indeed ;)

Comment: Ok, I'm at home and I've checked, but unfortunately, I even don't have such process. However, I've found something interesting, I'm adding it to above post.

Comment: Just to be sure, in Xfce you have the `Notification Area`. If you `right-click` on it and access `Properties`, you will see a list of applications that are "hidden". Is Skype listed there as hidden?